# Allow users to filter data contained in the data collection in MeteorJS

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-blaze

Hello application must allow users filtration data contained in the data collection. The filter has to be supported by the checkboxes. The user selects (checkbox) it interesting data (name, address ...) and submit your selection. The table below displays the selected data from the data collection.

Does anyone have an idea how it should look like the code that retrieves data from the collection of data, taking into account filtration made by the user.

My idea was. Get the value of the checkbox and save them in the array and the later inclusion of data from the array in the code to retrieve data from the collection using the subroutine find ().

```
'change .cd-checkbox-1': function(event, target) {
var x = event.target.checked;
Session.set("statevalue", x);
var array    = [];
if (Session.get("statevalue") === true) {
    $( "[name='inputCheckboxPodmiot']:checked" ).each( function( index, element ) {
      array.push( element.value );
    });
};
var arrayLength = array.length;
for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
    var abiRejestr = WkaRejestrAbi.find( {}, { fields: { array[i]: 1 } } );
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to use [Reactive Vars](https://docs.meteor.com/api/reactive-var.html). Sessions are not recommended as they pollute the global namespace.

Example code :

In main.html

```
<template name="test">
     <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1" name="name" value="data">Check Me
     <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox2" name="name" value="data">Check Me2
     <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox3" name="name" value="data">Check Me2
      {{showData}}
</template>
```

In Main.js

```
 var check_status='';
 //Reactive Var Initialization
 Template.main.onCreated(function (){
       check_status1=new ReactiveVar({});
       check_status2=new ReactiveVar({});
       check_status3=new ReactiveVar({});

 });

 Template.main.helpers({
       showData : function(){
           return Collection.find({$and : [{check_status1.get(),check_status2.get(),check_status3.get()}]}).fetch();
       }
 });

 Template.main.events({
      "change #checkbox1" : function(event) {
            if($(event.currentTarget).is(":checked").val())
              check_status1.set({field1: 'data1'});
            else
               check_status1.set({});
       },
       "change #checkbox2" : function(event) {
            if($(event.currentTarget).is(":checked").val())
              check_status2.set({field2: 'data2'});
            else
               check_status2.set({});
       },
       "change #checkbox3" :function(event) {
            if($(event.currentTarget).is(":checked").val())
               check_status3.set({field3: 'data2'});
            else
               check_status3.set({});
       },
 });
```

Explanation:

When we initialize the reactive var `check_status` we set the value equal to  `{}`. In the helper, at the time of rendering, the same data is passed to the query `Collection.find(check_status.get())` which is as good as *show all* data.

As soon as you click on the checkbox, the event described in the `Template.main.events` is triggered which sets the value of `check_status` to `{field: data}`. Since, this is a *reactive var*, the `showData` template is re run and this time the query is `Collection.find({field: data})`, so only fields, where `field` matched `'data'` is returned.

You will need to add the `reactive var` package(`meteor add reactive-var`) before using these commands.

Alternatively, you can also use [Tracker.autorun](https://docs.meteor.com/api/tracker.html) is you want to continue using `session` variables.

Comment: But how to solve the problem of data display when the checkboxes are few, and the user can select only one or all the checkboxes.
`<template name="test">
     <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1" name="name" value="name">Check Me
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1" name="surename" value="surename">Check Me
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1" name="adress" value="adress">Check Me
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1" name="city" value="city">Check Me
<button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">showData</button>
      <div>{{showData}}</div>
</template>`

Comment: Edited the answer. The idea is to use reactive var to make it reactive. You can play around in writing the mongodb queries. You can also use select multiple type input and save the results and array and do a query operation using `$or` or `$in` operators.

Comment: I have edited it further to be reactive when a checkbox is unselected.

Comment: Thank you for your help, but this code is not working properly:

`return Collection.find({$and : {check_status1.get(),check_status2.get(),check_status3.get()).fetch();`

While processing files with ecmascript (for target web.browser):
 client/main.js:31:56: Unexpected token (31:56)

Comment: code corrected. I forgot to close the braces. Kindly check the syntax as I haven't run them in my machine.

Comment: I checked the code on a machine running Linux meteor.js version 1.4.1.1 and 1.2.1. and the error persists

Comment: do you have a github repo or something where I can see the code.

Comment: change the line to this: `return WkaRejestrAbi.find({$and : [{check_status1.get(),check_status2.get(),check_status3.get()}]}).fetch();`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122199/discussion-between-ankit-and-samuraijack).